# How can I access a private class member in other class in c++(inheritance)

Tags: c++, inheritance, composition

In one class named Contact, It has private name(string) member, and the second class (base class) AddressBook, has private member Contact contacts[100], and I can't acces when I define in main like this:

```
AddressBook ab1;
cout<<"Enter Name"<<endl;
name=ab1.contacts[0].setName();
```

Comment: If `contacts` is `private` than you are not meant to access it. The `AddressBook` class will probably offer a member function to access contacts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between private, public, and protected inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance)

Comment: Sidenote: Instead of storing a fixed number of 100 `Contract`s, use a `std::vector<Contract>` and store the amount of contracts needed.

Comment: how can I exactly do that ? I mean how can I assign a vector value to array ?

Comment: you might wanna read up on encapsulation and what it's purposes are

Comment: How can I use set and get function on an object array ?

Comment: @Monstarules no matter how you inherit you cannot access a member that is private in the base. Thats not a duplicate

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 actually the answer as to why he can't do that is in there. François already answered the question in the comments for him as well.

Comment: @Monstarules well on a second thought it might be the right duplcate